# Can't figure out JOIN command

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts, join

I have two files and I'm trying to join them at a certain spot. I'd like to join them at the fourth column of the second file using the first column of the first. It's driving me nuts!

Here is what I'm trying:

```
join -j4 <(sort -k1 FirstFile.txt) <(sort -k4 SecondFile.txt)
```

---

FirstFile.txt:

```
24.136.152.171 US
24.136.152.171 US
24.136.152.171 US
```

---

SecondFile.txt

```
2014-08-03 00:00:00 User 24.136.152.171
2014-08-03 00:00:00 User 24.136.152.171
2014-08-03 00:00:00 User 24.136.152.171
```

---

Desired Output:

```
2014-08-03 00:00:00 User 24.136.152.171 US
2014-08-03 00:00:00 User 24.136.152.171 US
2014-08-03 00:00:00 User 24.136.152.171 US
```

Comment: Would you be happy to use python, and where does this command save the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default output format of `join` is to print the join field, then remaining fields from `FILE1` and then the remaining fields from `FILE2`, unless the format is specified with `-o`. Further, the option `-j4` means that join field is the 4th field in both FILE1 and FILE2. So you need to split `-j4` to `-1 1 -2 4` .

Try this:

```
join -o '2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 1.2' -2 4 -1 1 <(sort -k1 FirstFile.txt) <(sort -k4 SecondFile.txt)
```

Comment: Strange that I get 9 (identical) lines with this command instead of 3.

Comment: With the input in the question?

Comment: Yes I copied the files and used your command. Very strange. I wonder if the identical input lines are the cause. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hmm, no, I get 9 lines using those lines in a Ubuntu 20.04 docker image.

Answer (score 0):

You could us python.

Save the following in a file called `join.py` in your home area:

```python
ffile=open('FirstFile.txt','r').read().split('\n')       # Open the first file, read it and split it into a list at the newline character
sfile=open('SecondFile.txt','r').read().split('\n')      # Open the second file, read it and split it into a list at the newline character
minlen=min(len(ffile),len(sfile))                        # Get the lengths of both, and return the minimum so it doesn't break if they are different lengths.
ofile = [] # Create an empty list.    

for i in range (minlen):                                 # Loop for the length of the shortest list.
    ofile = ofile + [ffile[i]+sfile[i]]                  # Add the first item of the first list (the first line of the first file) to the first item of the second list (the first line of the second file).

outfile=open('outputfile','w')                           # Create an output file, called outputfile.txt in your home directory

outfile.write('\n'.join(ofile))                          # Write to the output file.
```

then run it with

```
python join.py
```

Comment: `join` joins when the join fields are identical. So something like `ofile = [a + b[1:] for (a,b) in zip (sfile, ffile) if a[3] == b[0]]` (at least, in Python 3).

Comment: I'm not good enough at python to even remotely understand that! Do post that as an answer tho!

Comment: It uses [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). I would post it if I was sure it would work. I haven't done Python in some time, so I am not sure. :)

Comment: No, string index out of range...

Comment: Ah. I assumed a split over `' '` as well, so that I could compare the 4th and 1st entries of the lines. Even then the newline at the end of each line will cause problems. Here, see this script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8055239/

Comment: I appreciate your answer but in the context of what I'm trying to achieve, this is extreme. i did save this and will probably use this in my next script.